# How can I find a DialogFragment by its Tag?

Tags: java, android

I've been looking for a solution to do this but I couldn't find it. 
I have a DialogFragment called ImportDialog, with a tag of the same name. How could I get this ImportDialog instance from my MainActivity?

Comment: `findFragmentById()` try it

Comment: I already tried it, but it returns the current fragment that is in the container, not the DialogFragment @someuser

Comment: paste [Minimal, Reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding an interface in my MainActivity and implementing it on my DialogFragment, that way I can pass data from the MainActivity to the Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment frg= getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
 if (frg!= null) {
        ft.remove(frg);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

Comment: findFragmentByTag returns null, even if when the tag is the right one

Comment: make sure you have imported the right library.i.e import android.app.DialogFragment;

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you opted your code?:

```
(ImportDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById([ID of layout here]);
```

I think it would help if you instantiated the Fragment or at least have it inflated. Only then will findFragmentById() work.

But then again, I did read that there are work arounds to this, such as using the findFragmentByTag Option if you haven't looked into that:

```
YourFramgent yourFragment = new YourFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "yourFragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And then to call it:

```
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourFragment");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official Android documentation, "commit" is an asynchronous operation.

> Calling commit() doesn't perform the transaction immediately. Rather, the transaction is scheduled to run on the main UI thread as soon as it is able to do so. If necessary, however, you can call commitNow() to run the fragment transaction on your UI thread immediately.

Hence if you want to get an instance of the fragment immediately after adding or replacing it to the container, then you should use "commitNow" instead of "commit". An example is shown below.

```
RetryDialogFragment().showNow(childFragmentManager, RetryDialogFragment.TAG)
val retryDialogFragment =
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(RetryDialogFragment.TAG) as RetryDialogFragment
```

However, you must also be mindful of the following fact when using commitNow.

> Note that commitNow is incompatible with addToBackStack. Alternatively, you can execute all pending FragmentTransactions submitted by commit() calls that have not yet run by calling executePendingTransactions(). This approach is compatible with addToBackStack.

For more reference on the same, checkout : [Commit is asynchronous](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#async)